# how to create unique array of object in deep nested array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, lodash, ecmascript-5

so i have a array in that a key have another array of object i need to make unique array of object from this array based on two key *level* and *userId* using lodash or vanila JavaScript
**for example**

```
const data = [
  {
    values: {
      output: [],
    }
  },
  {
    values: {
        output: [
        { level: 1, userId: "810", },
        { level: 1, userId: "811", },
        { level: 2, userId: "811", },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    values: {
        output: [
        { level: 1, userId: "810", },
      ],
    }
  },
  {
    values: {
        output: [
        { level: 1, userId: "810", },
        { level: 3, userId: "810", },
      ],
    }
  },
  {
    values: {
        output: [
        { level: 1, userId: "810", },
        { level: 3, userId: "810", },
      ],
    }
  }
];
```

and expected output is

```
let output =[
      { level: 1, userId: "810", },
      { level: 1, userId: "811", },
      { level: 2, userId: "811", },
      { level: 3, userId: "810", },
]
```

Comment: You can try
`const arr = data.map((obj) => obj.values.output).flat();`
`const uniq = _.unionBy(arr, JSON.stringify);`

Answer (score 0):

Get an array of all `output` properties with `_.flatMap()` (or `Array.flatMap()`, and then use `_.uniqBy()` to get only unique items. In the `_.uniqBy()` callback return a custom value by combining `level` and `userId` to a single string.

**ES5:**

```js
var data = [{"values":{"output":[]}},{"values":{"output":[{"level":1,"userId":"810"},{"level":1,"userId":"811"},{"level":2,"userId":"811"}]}},{"values":{"output":[{"level":1,"userId":"810"}]}},{"values":{"output":[{"level":1,"userId":"810"},{"level":3,"userId":"810"}]}},{"values":{"output":[{"level":1,"userId":"810"},{"level":3,"userId":"810"}]}}];

var result = _.uniqBy(
  _.flatMap(data, function(o) { return o.values.output; }), 
  function(o) { return o.level + '-' + o.userId; }
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

**ES6:**

```js
const data = [{"values":{"output":[]}},{"values":{"output":[{"level":1,"userId":"810"},{"level":1,"userId":"811"},{"level":2,"userId":"811"}]}},{"values":{"output":[{"level":1,"userId":"810"}]}},{"values":{"output":[{"level":1,"userId":"810"},{"level":3,"userId":"810"}]}},{"values":{"output":[{"level":1,"userId":"810"},{"level":3,"userId":"810"}]}}];

const result = _.uniqBy(
  _.flatMap(data, o => o.values.output), 
  o => `${o.level}-${o.userId}`
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: He's got this tagged as ecmascript-5

Comment: Thanks. The changes are minor, because lodash does the heavy lifting. The weird thing is that he uses a `const` and a `let` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very vanilla JS solution. This won't be fast on huge data sets but for sets like your example, it's not too bad. It first gathers all of your data together into a single array and then builds a new and duplicate-free array. If you need to be careful about overwriting the data that you pass in then you can clone it first.

```
function mergeAllData(data) {
  var allData = [];
  for (var i in data) {
    allData = allData.concat(data[i].values.output);
  }
  return allData;
}

function filterDuplicates(allData) {
  var ret = [];
  for (var i in allData) {
    var current = allData[i];
    ret.push(current);
    for (var j in allData) {
      if (isADuplicate(current, allData[i])) {
        allData.splice(j, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

function isADuplicate(t1, t2) {
  return t1.level === t2.level && t1.userId === t2.userId;
}

console.log(filterDuplicates(mergeAllData()));
```